# Как ускорить работу элемента System.Windows.Forms.ListView?

Tags: c#, listview

Столкнулся с проблемой в элементе управления System.Windows.Forms.ListView. При наличие в нем большого количества элементов, он начинает нагружать процессор при скроллинге и визуально "притормаживать".

Заполнение происходит с помощью своих методов отрисовки:

```
listView4.DrawColumnHeader += new DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventHandler(lv_DrawColumnHeader);
listView4.DrawSubItem += new DrawListViewSubItemEventHandler(lv_DrawSubItem);
```

В которых рисуются с помощью Graphics.DrawString, Graphics.DrawRectangle и CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox нужные мне элементы.

Есть ли возможность избавиться от глюков, либо же посоветуйте альтернативу(можно и платную) для замены этого элемента управления? Софт написан под Windows.Forms

Comment: При большом количестве элементов стоит использовать [виртуальный режми](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Фризы однозначно из-за постоянной отрисовки, попробуй использовать стандартные элементы. Из альтернатив хорошие это Telerik и DevExpress, оптимизация у них получше будет.

Comment: Виртуализация спасет отца русской демократии.